# Can a BNA file created on Mac be deployed on other Linux host?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I created and successfully deployed a BNA on my local Mac but had an error when I tried to deploy the existing BNA file onto a ubuntu host saying it could not find end of central directory?

"Eror: Can't find end of central directory: is this a zip file?"

Answer (score 0):

BNA files are platform agnostic and are simple zip files. There should be no problem taking a BNA file created on one platform and using it on a different platform. Not sure what has happened in your case but it looks like in the process of copying the file across it has been corrupted. You should be able to change the extension from bna to zip and use a tool like gunzip to unzip it. Also the linux file command should be able to detect the type of file it is so might be worth trying that to see what it reports on the ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when installing the bna file on the network with `composer install`. I didn't find anything on the web, however, in my case (and I am pretty sure in your as well) I am using a virtual machine, using a samba file share.

My environment uses vagrant together with a hyper-v hypervisor (ubuntu guest system). Even if your setup might vary, the problem probably is that for some vagrant versions (mine 2.1.4) the smb implementation is buggy. Zip/Unzip is not working properly and sometimes even files get scrabled up.

The only solution for me was to downgrade to an older vagrant version with a more stable smb implementation.